# FTDI VDIP1L File Creation "Bad Command"

Tags: arduino, ftdi

I'm using an FTDI VDIP1L with my Arduino Uno to log data to USB (Sandisk Cruzer 8 GB). The Arduino is programmed with Software Serial as available at http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial so I'm able to echo serial from the Arduino serial port monitor to/from the VDIP. The light on the USB stick is working (so it's alive) as are some of the Vinculum commands, e.g. DIR, IDDE, DSN, DVL, but anything related to actual files on the disk doesn't seem to work (make that OPW; I haven't tried reading or writing since I'm using a blank flash drive and they don't apply yet).

The Uno is powered with the external adapter, and also connected to PC by the USB cable. Arduino--VDIP1L connections are as follows: (Arduino--VDIP1L):
5V--5V; GND--GND; 11(SW TX)--AD1(RX); 10(SW RX)--AD0(TX); GND--AD3(CTS);

The VDIP1L has the latest version of the VDAP firmware, "MAIN 03.69VDAPF
RPRG 1.00R" as returned by the FWV command.

Syntax used:
OPW DATAFILE.TXT

I've tried sending it all at once and in parts. When I try it in parts the OPW generates no complaint (or response for that matter) by then I get "Bad Command" when I send the file name or part thereof.

Anyone know why the file commands won't work?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Still not able to get this working with the Arduino Serial monitor, but I have noticed a couple of things about said monitor. There is a drop-down menu that allows you to select between "no line ending", "carriage return", "newline", and "carriage return+newline". The monitor will append a carriage return and/or a line feed to your text entry depending on your selection.

Now I don't know why that wasn't enough to get the commands to the VDIP. Perhaps the serial monitor adds a carriage return (when this option is selected) after each block of text, in which case my command would have been "OPW " 'carriage return' "datafile.txt" 'carriage return', while the VDIP wants "OPW datafile.txt" 'carriage return'.

I tried this syntax with Putty in place of the Arduino serial monitor and got it working, along with writing to the file, so the question is pretty much closed as far as I'm concerned.

Cheers,